# Flutter Slider - doesn't show label

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've this Slider but it's not showing the label anywhere.

Is this the normal behaviour?

```
double _value;

  _buildEditModeWidget() {
    return Expanded(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 60,),
        Slider(
        label: "Power: ",
          min: 0,
          max: 9,
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (double newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _value = newValue;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    ));
  }





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(width: 1))),
      height: editMode ? _editModeHeight : _readOnlyHeight,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 0.9,
              child: (extension(widget.model.team.shieldImage) != ".svg")
                  ? Image.network(
                      widget.model.team.shieldImage,
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                    )
                  : SvgPicture.network(
                      widget.model.team.shieldImage,
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    ),
            ),
          ),
          ScopedModelDescendant<TeamModel>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, TeamModel model) {
              return editMode ? _buildEditModeWidget() : _buildReadOnlyWidget();
            },
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: editMode
                    ? IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.model.updateTeam(_teamNameController.text, 0);
                      editMode = false;
                    });
                  },
                )
                    : IconButton(
                  key: _key,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      editMode = true;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
              ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try set up divisions value to 9. You will see the label on each step of the values. seems like this label property is not a text label of the slider.

Comment: Can we add the label without division

Comment: @ShahryarRafique check my answer

Answer (score 15):

Set `ShowValueIndicator.always` in your `ThemeData` as follows:

```dart
ThemeData(
  sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
    showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
  )
)
```

Check docs for more details: [ShowValueIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ShowValueIndicator.html)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for Slider.adaptive on iOS/macOS

Comment: `ShowValueIndicator.always` is poorly named.  It doesn't cause the indicator to "always" be shown, it instead causes the indicator to be shown for all types of sliders (i.e. discrete and continuous).  Per the docs, it also does not work with `Slider.adaptive` as @IcyIcicle noted.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this and what seems to fix it is to set up the divisions property of the Slider

and interpolate the string Power with the changing value

```
Slider(
                        value: sliderValue,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 9,
                        divisions: 9,
                        label: "Power: ${sliderValue.round().toString()}",
                        onChanged: (double value) {
                          setState(() {
                            sliderValue = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution in Flutter Github issues.

```
            child: SliderTheme(
              data: SliderThemeData(
                  showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.onlyForContinuous),
              child: Slider(
                value: _distanceValue,
                min: 5.0,
                max: 20.0,
                label: _distanceValue.toString(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _distanceValue = value;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
```

By this we can specify theme for individual sliders in the application. No need to change the MaterialApp ThemeData.

[GH Issue Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34704#issuecomment-625103022)

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly well for my use case!

Answer (score -1):

```
double sliderValue = 2.0;
Theme(
                            data: ThemeData(
                                sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
                              overlayColor: Colors.red,
                              showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
                              tickMarkShape: SliderTickMarkShape.noTickMark,
                              rangeTickMarkShape: RoundRangeSliderTickMarkShape(tickMarkRadius: 0),
                              valueIndicatorColor: Color(0xFFFEC92B),
                              valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                            )),
                            child: Slider(
                              activeColor: Color(0xFFFEC92B),
                              inactiveColor: Color(0xFF9E9E9E),
                              min: 2,
                              max: 20,
                              value: sliderValue,

                              ///division value set same as max value
                              divisions: 20,
                              label: sliderValue.toInt().toString(),
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                newValue = double.parse(newValue.toStringAsFixed(0));
                                setState(() => sliderValue = newValue);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

on Slider witget to label vision, property  add your code ; "division" property,(Lütfen division propertysini kullanın aksi halde slider da label görünmez),